Give 2 week notice before or after a weeklong company team building retreat?
I have signed a written offer and cleared the background check. A weeklong company team building retreat is scheduled in two weeks. Should I give my two week notice before the retreat or after I come back? I will be starting my new company in 3 weeks.

Please edit your question and add a tag about your country and maybe federal state if that is relevant. People answering you have already taken a guess and assumed you live in the US and in an at-will state. Maybe they are correct. Maybe not. You should not rely on people guessing for you and then you guessing which guess is best. Please state your country.

Can you not let the new company know that you might be free a week earlier? (Some will have very rigid induction plans, some very flexible) How problematic would an extra week without wages be?

This is totally dependent on the OP's situation. I know someone who quit just before going on the free cruise the company gave him for doing a difficult task.

If the team building is in 2 weeks, you have a 2 week notice and your new job starts in 3 weeks the maths are clear and the question answers itself.

You should give the 2-week notice to your manager ASAP (before the retreat).
Next, you ask your manager if he wants you to work for these 2 weeks (to transfer the knowledge) or to join the retreat.
Then, your manager will tell you the answer.
No matter what his answer is, you will follow his answer because he represents the company. In the end, you will be proud of your work ethics and integrity.

If you're planning to start your new job in 3 weeks, you should give notice at most 1 week from now so you have two weeks between giving your notice and your last day.
Waiting until the 2 week point would be safest in that you at most risk losing 2 weeks of income if your old employer immediately lets you go.
Doing that risks souring relations somewhat with your old bosses though.  They'll only have 1 week of knowledge transfer from you before everyone else goes off on the retreat.  (You'll almost certainly be disinvited after giving notice.)  If you trust your old company not to screw you, giving an additional week of notice so there's more time to transfer knowledge would be a good will gesture.
The risk you take is that they decide to make your last day before everyone else leaves for the retreat.
